# firebase startAt() endAt() methods

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am would like to use the `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods but I do not fully understand how they work.

Assuming I have the current database

```
"users" : {
    "someUser1" : {
      "email" : "oneEmail",
      "someOtherInfo" : "OneInfo",
      "username" : "someUser1"
    }
    "someUser2" : {
      "email" : "twoEmail",
      "someOtherInfo" : "twoInfo",
      "username" : "someUser2"
    },
    "someUser3" : {
      "email" : "threeEmail",
      "someOtherInfo" : "threeInfo",
      "username" : "someUser3"
    },
    "someUser4" : {
      "email" : "fourEmail",
      "someOtherInfo" : "fourInfo",
      "username" : "someUser4"
    }
  }
```

Now this data will be appended onto a RecyclerView. So initially I want to only get the first 2 elements (`someUser1` and `someUser2`), then when the user scrolls to the bottom of the recyclerView it gets the other 2 elements.

The recyclerView is fully setup and working, I just need to get the elements from the DB now but I don't understand how the 2 methods work, If i did:

```
users = myDB.getReference("users").orderByChild("email").startAt(0).endAt(2);
```

Would this suffice to get the first 2 elements?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below attached:

[image]

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference();
DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabaseReference.child("order")

node.limitToLast(2).orderByChild("timestamp")
                   .addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);

private ValueEventListener mTypingValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + snapshot.getValue());
            // Your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    };
```

Comment: Push elements have unique id based on the current timestamp (offset to match server time). This means that each record is naturally sorted at the end and that they maintain a chronological order.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html
There is no need to store time stamp explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by `limitToLast()`, Here is the code:

```
DatabaseReference node;

node.limitToLast(AppConstants.SIZE)
                    .orderByChild(YourOwnSortMethod)
                    .addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);

private ValueEventListener mTypingValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + snapshot.getValue());
            // Your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    };
```

What this does is,

Dataset = A, C, B, E, F

`orderByChild` (ascending) = A, B, C, E, F

`limitToLast` (2) = E, F

Comment: If we had the dataset you provided I want to first retrieve A,C then on next call receive B,E and last call receive F. Also in your code shouldnt it be  .addValueEventListener(mTypingValueEventListener) instead of .addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener)

Comment: Then `descending` the data set. If you want to get first two object from this A, C, B, E, F, then you have to set timestamp when you creates each dataset. Then you can order by timestamp :)

Comment: Okay, I am close to understanding how to do this. So I already have a timestamp for each dataset how would I now order by this? would it be .orderByChild(time) where time is the timestamp for each dataset?

Comment: would you be able to give an example? it would be much appropriated

Comment: @TerribleCoderSad see the below answer. Thanks!

Comment: how retrieve the next 2 element i mean B , C

Comment: There is no way to get batch of data from firebase data set. You can retrieve dataset by 2, 4, 6 ...

Comment: Can be achieved but will take two different service call